# Comma Delimiter Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js, multidimensional-array

I have an array (call it array[]), with elements of the following format separated by a comma:

```
array[0] = abc, def, 123, ghi
```

How can I pass this into another multi-dimensional array (lets say arrayTwo[]) such that arrayTwo is as follows:

```
arrayTwo[0][0] = "abc"
arrayTwo[0][1] = "def"
arrayTwo[0][2] = "123"
arrayTwo[0][3] = "ghi"
```

I am really unsure about the comma as a delimiter portion (use split()?). I believe the looping part should not be too difficult for me to handle. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the items by `,\s*` regex which is comma followed by zero or more spaces.  This will create an array.  Then just insert that array into the appropriate element of `arrayTwo`.

```
arrayTwo = array.map(function (item) {
    return item.split(/,\s*/)
});
```

Unrolled slightly it would look like:

```
arrayTwo = [];
for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    var item = array[x].split(/,\s*/);
    arrayTwo[x] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
        arrayTwo[x][i] = item[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is exactly one space after each comma, `split(', ')` might be faster.

Comment: Quick follow up. How would I amend the split(/,\s*/) if I want to push items that are separated by either a comma or a space (i.e. it may be a space w no comma)

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 `/,|\s/` will work -- that is either one comma or one space